# JavaFX and IntelliJ 14 Alternative Self Packaging to EXE

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I am trying to self package a JavaFX app in IntelliJ 14. This has been wasting my time for past 2 days. It took me less to develop the app. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

What I want is a self-contained package that will run on any platform (mainly Windows). Now I am using Ubuntu and I want this:

1 - Using my current OS (Ubuntu 14.04) I want to create an `exe` file that will act as an installer or simple executable for windows whatever it is 
produced.

I tried this, http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html and Excelsior JET, the first one does not create a self-contained app, and the second one did not run.

2 - I tried this http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm

I tried using the `javafxpackager` which in Java8 it has been renamed into `javapackager`, and I ran this:

`javapackager -deploy -native exe -srcfiles src/ -outdir out/artifacts -outfile GreekTest -appclass foo.Main`

What it did was to just generate a bunch of java files in the ourdir. No `exe`.

From the link I posted above,

[image]

First of all I have no such XML file as in my JavaFX app directory that has a task `<fx:deploy>` is this generated by the user?

3 - IntelliJ Build Artifacts Tools just generate a jar file, no-self contained app.

4 - I also want to avoid Maven/Ant as I don't know how to use it.

Any help?

Comment: are you using an IDE? If yes, which one?

Comment: Check the title. it says there. I also mention the name of it in the description

Comment: my bad, I didn't know about intelliJ, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Capsule](http://blog.paralleluniverse.co/2015/09/10/capsule-1-0/).

Re Excelsior JET not working, you must be on a 64-bit Ubuntu system, and it needs some 32-bit libraries. Here is an excerpt from the [installation instructions](http://www.excelsiorjet.com/evaluate#install):

> **Important notice for 64-bit Linux users:**
>
> As of version 10.5, some key components of the 64‑bit version of
>   Excelsior JET for Linux remain 32‑bit. Most 64‑bit Linux systems do
>   not have the 32‑bit libraries installed by default. If you receive a
>   "No such file or directory" or "cannot execute binary file" message on
>   an attempt to run any Excelsior JET component, or one of its graphical
>   tools fails on startup with
>
> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Frame`
>
> you need to install those libraries.
>
> On Ubuntu/Debian, the procedure used to be as simple as:
>
> `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`
>
> but in the latest versions you have to list the libraries explicitly:
>
> `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxi6:i386 libxtst6:i386`
>
> The list of libraries and installation procedure in other distros may
>   differ.
>
> (Full 64‑bit port is our top priority, but doing it right takes time.
>   Please bear with us.)

In any case, it won't help you create "a self-contained package that will run on any platform (mainly Windows)." First, it creates a native executable that will run on *either* Windows, OS X, *or* Linux, but not on two or three of these. Second, it does not support cross-compilation as of version 10.5, so you need Excelsior JET for Windows to create a Windows EXE.